# Perform an equation, resulting in a new column

Tags: r

The wording of my question may not be great so I will try and illustrate via this example.

```
A   Rank
0.5 1
0.6 2
0.7 3
0.8 4
0.9 5
1.0 6
```

I would like to add a column with a result of this formula:

```
(i/m)/Q
```

Where:

- i = the rank of each value in column A (e.g 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
- m = 6 (total rows)
- Q = 0.05

The result would then provide another column with the result of that equation. I have 730 rows so would like to perform this instead of doing it manually for each one.

```
A   Rank C
0.5 1    (1/6)0.05
0.6 2    (2/6)0.05
0.7 3    (3/6)0.05
0.8 4    (4/6)0.05
0.9 5    (5/6)0.05
1.0 6    (6/6)0.05
```

Many Thanks

Comment: `df$C <- (df$Rank/dim(df)[1])*0.05`

Comment: Try `df$C <- (df$Rank / nrow(df)) / 0.05`

Comment: Thank you! Duck & Darren Tsai